# problem Simple-cdd postinst modify a file

Tags: debian

I'm using simple-cdd to create a pure blend debian installer.

I want to add a log file to the script, ex:

NAME.postinst contains:

```
 touch mylog 
 echo "Hello this works" >> mylog
```

The results after instalation is the file
but empty.

why!!!!!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, check if NAME.postinst is a executable shell script (#!/bin/sh at the begining and executable permissions on the file,for example with chmod +x) Then, when postinst gets executed, your system still runs from the ramdisk on cd, so when your scripts is executed it creates the log somewhere on the ramdisk, and after reboot it will be gone. The installed systems resides in /target, so there you should make your log.

I think it should look more like this:

`#!/bin/sh`

`touch /target/mylog`

`echo "Hello this works">>/target/mylog`

Comment: Yeah... it is an executable shell script